# How do I get rid of local variable referenced before assignment error?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to make a simple program that generates a board on which you move around as X. 
Code:

```
from msvcrt import getch
import os

board = []

for x in range(20):
    board.append(["O"] * 20)

def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print " ".join(row)

def keys(coordx, coordy):
    global coordY
    global coordX
    key = ord(getch())
    if key == 97:
        coordx -= 1
    elif key == 100:
        coordx += 1
    elif key == 115:
        coordy -= 1
    elif key == 119:
        coordy += 1

def play(coordx, coordy):
    global coordY
    global coordX
    while True:
        board[coordx][coordy] = "X"
        print_board(board)

        keys(coordx, coordy)

        os.system('cls')

coordX = 10
coordY = 10

play(coordX, coordY)
```

Every time i want the program to change the value of coordX or coordY i get UnboundLocalError: local variable coordY/coordX refferenced before assignment. I tried different methods - making variables global, making arguments for functions instead of using the variables while defining functions and nothing worked.

Comment: The error you are getting is not happening with the code you pasted. Where exactly are you trying to assign to coordX and coordY? BTW, see my post on [Local vs Global variables](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/263/variable-scope-and-binding/20367/local-vs-global-scope#t=201609042140421595592) for details on that error.

Comment: Why do you declare `global coordY` and `global coordX` in your functions when you never try to assign to those variables?

Comment: Assigned them, so you can clearly see what is happening

Answer (score 1):

Once you call `play`, you never make any assignments to either `coordX` or `coordY`, which would explain why they never change.